# Why is my app incompatible with Nexus 4?

Tags: android, nexus-4

My app is incompatible with Google Nexus 4. Why? Here's my manifest (all of it except for `<application/>` part):

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
    android:required="true" />
```

P. S. I've had reports that Samsung Galaxy S3 stopped detecting USB devices after updating to Jelly Bean. I wonder if it is related.
On the other hand, Nexus 10 also runs Jelly Bean and works perfectly.

Comment: Nexus 4 seems to have problems with USB OTG. See:
http://www.phonearena.com/news/Nexus-4-and-USB-on-the-go-are-no-go_id36997

Comment: @Findus: Huh? That is... Unexpected. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
    android:required="true" />
```

Set this to false and it should work.  Not always, but generally usb hosts need to have the full USB port, not a micro one.

Comment: That is not a solution, and what you say doesn't make much sense. Socket form-factor has nothing to do with the device having USB host and Android having support for it. At any rate, setting it to false will do more evil than good.

Comment: I said generally. If you look at most tablets for instance, the Micro USB connection cannot be used as a USB host connection, while the full USB port (when available) can be. The reason I said to set it to false is because it's not a viable option since it's not available on the Nexus 4: http://www.androidcentral.com/google-edits-nexus-4-online-help-manual-removes-reference-usb-gadget-support

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have hard time believing that is the cause, but seems that way.

Comment: No worries, good luck.  We couldn't believe it when we heard it as that was a selling point.